# Read my Facebook application's publish stream posts

Tags: perl, facebook, publish

I created a number of posts on behalf of the user by issuing an HTTP POST request to (PROFILE_ID/feed) with the publish_stream. Sample:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?
```

I got everyone's post ids, but I when I'm trying to access and read them I getting a "false" respond..

Comment: Is the read using the same authentication?

Comment: you mean if i have reading authentication?, the anwser is no.

Answer (score 1):

I was at a Perl Mongers meeting (Los Angeles) last week where the presentation was on integration with Facebook.  In particular, one of the developers was discussing his new module, [Facebook::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Facebook%3a%3aGraph).  He indicated that in producing the module he learned a lot about what Facebook would do if you request information but don't provide everything it is expecting in your request.  Your problem description sounds like a case in point.

The module's description is:

> This is a Perl interface to the Facebook Graph API
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api. With this module you can
>   currently query public Facebook data, query privileged Facebook data,
>   and build a privileged Facebook application. See the TODO for all that
>   this module cannot yet do.

There is a companion POD for that module called [Facebook::Graph::Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Facebook%3a%3aGraph%3a%3aCookbook).  It contains a couple of cookbook examples.

While the module is still fairly new and under development, I know that the individual who worked on it has spent many hours working on it in a professional setting where solid results are expected.  I'm confident that he "got it right."  It's currently being used by a high-traffic well known website.

There's no point trying to re-implement interfacing with this API when someone else has done a good job of it already.  Through the discussion that took place after the presentation I know that the module has gone through extensive testing.  That's not to say it's perfect, but it's probably a hundred or more man-hours further along the journey.

It's my suggestion that you implement your Facebook Graph interactions through using this module.  I suspect when you do, many of your headaches will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ask for the read_stream permission to do this